# Create value nested generic type and assigne it to variable

Tags: c#, generics, nested, nested-generics

here I created the variable appointment of type `Pair<Pair <int, int>, String>` I would like to create a value of this type and assign it to appointment.

Could somebody help me?
 I am new to C# and programming.

```
Pair< Pair<int, int>, String> appointment = new Pair<Pair<int,int>,String>;
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've also created a `Pair` type? We'd have to see that to know how to help you - and if you're going to call a constructor, you'll need brackets...

Comment: (I'd also strongly recommend that you simply declare a type with two integers and a string instead of this confusing generic type, by the way.)

Comment: I am just following this exercise sheet Jon http://people.cs.aau.dk/~bt/JAVA-CSHARP/CSharpExercises.pdf

Comment: Pair< Pair<int, int>, String> appointment = new Pair<Pair<int, int>, String>(new Pair<int, int>(48, 48), "string");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Pair` has a constructor with two arguments

```
Pair<Pair<int,int>,string> appointment = new Pair<Pair<int,int>,string>(
    new Pair<int,int>(x, y),
    "hello"
);
```

or more concise

```
var appointment = new Pair<Pair<int,int>,string>(
    new Pair<int,int>(x, y),
    "hello"
);
```

or with object initializers (assuming `Pair` has two properties named `Arg1` and `Arg2`)

```
var appointment = new Pair<Pair<int,int>,string> {
    Arg1 = new Pair<int,int> { Arg1 = x, Arg2 = y),
    Arg2 = "hello"
};
```

or if you want to create an empty `Pair`

```
var appointment = new Pair<Pair<int,int>,string>();
```

Comment: Thank you Olivier, exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for the detailed explanation/options. helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Pair class have the following public properties with public setters:

```
public Pair<T, T> Nested { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set ; }
```

then also you can do:

```
var appoinment = new Pair<Pair<int,int>,string>
{
     Nested = new Pair<int,int>(1, 2),   
     Name = "Eric"
};
```

Comment: interesting. Eric I wasn't aware of we can do with public setters